# Obtener día y fecha en español - ReportViewer RDLC C#

Tags: c#, rdlc, reportviewerreporte

Estoy utilizando **Report Viewer** en la expresión `=Now()` para mostrar la fecha.

Pero me enseña en inglés la fecha:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Cómo mostrar la fecha español?

Answer (score 3):

Si solo vas a tener un solo idioma en tu reporte podrias ir a modificar el lenguaje de dicho rdlc.

Para eso debes ir a las propiedades del Reporte  y ubicar la propiedad para cambiar el lenguaje (propierdad Languaje)
Puedes colocar el codigo de lenguaje por ejemplo [es-419 para español latinoamerica](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_code)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Enlaces que te pueden servir de ayuda o guia

- [Report Definition Language SSRS](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/reporting-services/reports/report-definition-language-ssrs?view=sql-server-2017)
- [Codigo Lenguaje es-419 para español latinoamerica](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_code)

Espero que te sirva de ayuda o guia

Answer (score 1):

Con un par de líneas de código puedes lograr esto agregando la región y el idioma

```
CultureInfo RegionIdioma = new CultureInfo("es-ES");
DateTime.Now.ToString(RegionIdioma);
```

puedes usar otros como:

"es-MX"

"es-AR"

"es-CL"

etc